# Can't see my service traces in Jaeger UI (local node, Docker for Mac)

Tags: kubernetes, opentracing, jaeger

I'm trying to play around with Jaeger and open-tracing in my local k8s node (Docker for Mac) and having some trouble see traces in the UI.

I'm using the Jaeger operator and deployment annotations to inject the jaeger sidecar. The Jaeger cr is configured to sample constantly every request.
Up until this point, everything seems to be fine but when I send some HTTP traffic to my pods (Through nginx-ingress) I can see it coming but can't find any traces in Jaeger UI.

From reading the documentation, these steps should've implicitly collect and send the traces. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? i am having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable open tracing in nginx ingress controller.

To enable the instrumentation we must enable OpenTracing in the configuration ConfigMap:

```
data:
  enable-opentracing: "true"
```

To enable or disable instrumentation for a single Ingress, use the enable-opentracing annotation:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-opentracing: "true"
```

You must also set the host to use when uploading traces:

```
jaeger-collector-host: jaeger-agent.default.svc.cluster.local
```

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/third-party-addons/opentracing/

Comment: Good to know that traces are available in the ingress level but It doesn't solve my issue. Traces from my services (not necessarily passing through ingress) still can't be seen.